# How to convert int to byte in C?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I would like to convert an int to a byte in C.

In Java, I'd write:

```
int num = 167;
byte b = num.toByte(); // -89
```

In C:

```
int num = 167;
???
```

Comment: `int8_t b = (int8_t) num;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`byte` is a java signed integer type with a range of `-128` to `127`.
The corresponding type in C is `int8_t` defined in `<stdint.h>` for architectures with 8-bit bytes. It is an alias for `signed char`.

You can write:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void f() {
    int num = 167;
    int8_t b = num;  // or signed char b = num;
    ...
```

If your compiler emits a warning about the implicit conversion to a smaller type, you can add an explicit cast:

```
    int8_t b = (int8_t)num;  // or signed char b = (signed char)num;
```

Note however that it is much more common to think of 8-bit bytes as unsigned quantities in the range `0` to `255`, for which one would use type `uint8_t` or `unsigned char`. The reason java `byte` is a signed type might be that there is no unsigned type in this language, but it is quite confusing for non-native readers.

`byte` can also be defined as a typedef:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;  // 0-255;
```

or

```
typedef signed char byte;    // -128-127;
```

Do not use type `char` because it is implementation defined whether this type is signed or unsigned by default. Reserve type `char` for the characters in C strings, although many functions actually consider these to be unsigned: `strcmp()`, functions from `<ctype.h>`...

Comment: "Note however that C programmers usually prefer to think of 8-bit bytes as unsigned quantities" Not just C programmers. All computer scientists and computer engineers too. Apparently Java `byte` was designed by some special snowflakes.

Comment: @Lundin: java has no unsigned types, I should probably rephrase this part.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply cast to a byte:

```
unsigned char b=(unsigned char)num;
```

Note that if `num` is more than 255 or less than 0 C won't crash and simply give the wrong result.

Comment: After edits, the result is well-defined. "Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type."
until the value is in the range of the new type.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such type as Byte in native C. Although if you don't want to import new libs, you can create one like this :

```
typedef unsigned char Byte
```

And then create any variable you'd like with it :

```
int bar = 15;
Byte foo = (Byte)bar
```

Answer (score 3):

In computer science, the term *byte* is well-defined as an 8 bit chunk of raw data. Apparently Java uses a different definition than computer science...

- `-89` is *not* the value `167` "converted to a byte". `167` already fits in a byte, so no conversion is necessary.
- `-89` is the value `167` converted to *signed 2's complement* with 8 bits representation.
- The most correct type to use for signed 2's complement 8 bit integers in C is `int8_t` from `stdint.h`.
- Converting from `int` to `int8_t` is done implicitly in C upon assignment. There is no need for a cast.

  ```
  int num = 167;
  int8_t b = num;
  ```